# Adding another word in front of post url

Tags: permalinks, urls

I have a wordpress website with bunch of posts. 
My problem is that I need to change the URLs from

```
website.com/post-name
```

to

```
website.com/specialword/post-name
```

The "specialword" is what I need to add in front of those post names, but ONLY for the post type - posts.

Can someone help me?

I need this badly, mostly because of the SEO purposes so I can keep the URLs from the previous website that wasn't done in wordpress.

Thank you!
Slavisa

Answer (score 2):

You can do it from `Settings > Permalinks`.

Select the `Custom Structure` radio button, and put this in the text field next to it:

```
/myspecialword/%postname%
```

Works.

Comment: I know that, but I need this setting applied ONLY to post type posts, not all types of posts (pages, custom post types, etc)

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Of course I have, and it works fine for posts and pages, but the custom post type pages have the url:
/myspecialword/custom-post-type/%postname%

Comment: Ohh yes... Cuz the special word gets appended after the url. I guess you might need a URL rewrite.

Comment: Adding rewrite rule won't be sufficient in this case. If you do this, get_permalink still will be generating wrong links for such custom post type...

Comment: but it will also redirect from %postname% to /myspecialword/%postname% ? or it has to be done in htaacess ?

Comment: I think you can try adding a new permalink rule. I have lost touch with it for a while so I might not be able to give you an example. As far as I remember, no custom WordPress URLs require you to touch the htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only (the easiest) solution is to change `permastruct`s for custom post types after registering them and add your 'magic word' to permalink structure.

So set (in parmalinks settings) your permalink structure to: `/my-magic-word/%postname%/` and then manually modify permastructs of your custom post types.

You can do this like so (add it to your functions.php file):

```
function my_init() {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    // Let's assume you register your CPT Books in here
    $args = array( 'public' => true, 'label' => 'Books' );
    register_post_type( 'book', $args );

    // after registering your CPT, you have to change it's permastruct
    $wp_rewrite->extra_permastructs['book']['struct'] = "book/%book%";  // it's without 'my-magic-word' - you should do this for every CPT that should not have 'my-magic-word' in url
}
add_action('init', 'my_init');
```

Then go to permalink settings and save them to flush rewrite rules.

PS. I think you could try to use `with_front` param, but I'm not sure if it will be easier (or if it even will work) than this solution.